# Microsoft Word Macro duplicate buttons on "Design mode"

Tags: microsoft-word, macros

I am just learning "Macros" to automate word documents, but the first problem that I have is when I go off the "Design mode," the design commands don't disappear, but instead the User Commands overlap them.

Here are a couple of images of what I mean:

On design mode:

[image: On design mode]]

On user mode:

[image: On user mode]]

I've run the file in another computer and it worked just fine, so I decided to reinstall my MS word and it worked, but I don't know what happened that now the same problem pops again.

Any idea?

Comment: I think I'm facing a similar issue. I posted a question here: https://superuser.com/questions/1482030/microsoft-word-option-buttons-duplicating-moving-from-initial-position

Comment: Is it possible this is related to having a dual monitor setup? That fixed my issue.