# Microsoft Word Option Buttons Duplicating/Moving From Initial Position

Tags: microsoft-word, vba

I'm trying to establish option buttons (radio) in a MS Word Document. When I add the buttons, they appear fine in design mode, but the buttons jump/duplicate to an unexpected position when I exit design mode.

[image: view in design mode]

[image: after change]

I've tinkered with the button properties and run searches for similar titles as this post and don't see anything that matches my issue (except [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1463718/microsoft-word-macro-duplicate-buttons-on-design-mode) which is also unanswered).

Here are the properties of one of the buttons:

[image]

I'll upvote almost anything that's useful, and will be sure to accept any answer that solves this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was related to having a dual monitor setup. When I moved my Word Application to my laptop monitor (instead of my huge adjacent monitor), the document displayed as I expected.